# PointerOver visual state not working on buttons in MAUI Content Page

Tags: xamarin, maui

I am making an app with some buttons and I added some visual states that target buttons. The buttons have the correct color in the "Normal" state, but when I try to hover over them and activate the "PointerOver" state, they do not change color like they are supposed to. I have looked over the dotnet gitub on the visual states and I am sure I am coding it properly for what I can see. Any insight on this issue would be great.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="New.BBM.HMI.MAUI.Pages.Home"
             Title="Home"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="navButtons"
            TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="BankGothicMedBT"/>
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="70"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Lime" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="36" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Pink" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightBlue" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" RowDefinitions="20*,*" ColumnDefinitions="1.5*,15*,5*" ColumnSpacing="5">
        <!--Left side Nav bar-->
        <Grid x:Name="navBar" Margin="5,5,0,0" VerticalOptions="Start" RowSpacing="10" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto">
            <ImageButton x:Name="imgLogo" Clicked="GoToWebsite" Source="icon.png" HeightRequest="70" />
            <Button x:Name="btnHome" Clicked="GoToHome" Text="Home" Grid.Row="1" BorderWidth="2" Style="{StaticResource navButtons}" />
            <Button x:Name="btnToolPage" Clicked="GoToToolPage" Text="Tool&#10;Page" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource navButtons}" />
            <Button x:Name="btnMessages" Clicked="GoToMessages" Text="Messages" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource navButtons}" />(https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
            <Button x:Name="btnLaser" Clicked="GoToLaser" Text="Laser" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource navButtons}" />
            <Button x:Name="btnSettings" Clicked="GoToSettings" Text="Settings" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource navButtons}" />
        </Grid>
        <!--Center Div-->
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Blue">
            
        </Grid>
        <!--Right side Operator Panel-->
        <Grid Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="Yellow">

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pakpm.gif) is a short GIF of what is happening.

- I tried creating the visual state per-button.
- I then tried to do it in a style that targets all buttons.
- I then went ahead and copied/pasted the example visual states from Microsoft and the buttons are lime, but will not go light blue on hover. I did this to make sure I was not making any syntax mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Xamarin, this **PointerOver** feature is not included.
But if you use Maui, **PointerOver** feature has now been incuded. You should use .NET 7.0 instead of .NET6.0. Also, the  **PointerGestureRecognizer** could be used to  detect when the mouse pointer enters, exits, and moves within a view.

I tried your code in .NET 7.0 and it worked well. So upgrade it and have a try.

For more information, you could refer to [What's new in .NET MAUI for .NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/blob/main/docs/whats-new/dotnet-7.md#new-functionality).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll go ahead an upgrade from .net6.0